# Regex to remove everything before second to last forward slash

Tags: regex, r

Here is an example string

```
https://www.facebook.com/pages/Something/976313416535/
```

What regex can extract the "`Something`" from that string?

```
sub(".*[/@]", "", x)
```

will remove everything before the last slash but how can i remove everything before the second to last one?

Comment: Do you want to extract `Something` or `/Something/976313416535/`?  Your description isn't consistent.

Answer (score 0):

this regex will find "something".

```
^.*\/(.*)\/.*\/$
```

replace it with

```
\1
```

it is working on https://regex101.com/ for all (PCRE (PHP), ECMAScript, (JavaScript), Python, Golang) but it refused to work within notepad+ find replace.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know r language, but here is a PCRE regex that works for you (at least at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Lw5eXP/1)), it matches the second last item in the path (i.e. `Something`)

```
^.+/\K[^/]+(?=/[^/]+/)
```

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of string
  .+        # 1 or more any character
  /         # a slash
  \K        # forget all we have seen until this position
  [^/]+     # 1 or more non slash
  (?=       # start lookahead, zero-length assertion to make sure we have after:
    /       # a slash
    [^/]+   # 1 or more non slash (the string wanted)
    /       # a slash
  )         # end lookahead
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex

```
/(.*\/)([^/]*)(\/[^/]*\/)$/m
```

will find:

```
https://www.facebook.com/pages/ (group 1)
Something (group 2)
/976313416535/ (group 3)
```

you can replace it with whatever you want. In Javascript:

```
const regex = /(.*\/)([^/]*)(\/[^/]*\/)$/m;
const str = `https://www.facebook.com/pages/Something/976313416535/`;
let m = str.replace(regex,"$1whatever_you_want$3");
console.log(m); 

//Output - https://www.facebook.com/pages/whatever_you_want/976313416535/
```

You can see it working here [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/yt7GzH/3) and end match here [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/yt7GzH/2)